# Question relate to Re Deployment of onchain program

Tags: solana-program, deploy, mainnet, redeploy

I guess Im new, and my question maybe related to that...

1. I deployed a Smart Contract to mainnet-beta.
2. I got a Program ID."ABxhuh61R8QsvQFCmqy******"
3. I placed that program ID in the Anchor.toml:
   [programs.mainnet]
   metaplex_anchor_nft = "ABxhuh61R8QsvQFCmqy******"
4. I also added that id to the declare in the lib.rs
5. I want to redeploy it.  Solana Program deploy /target/deploy/*.so
6. Solana return that I need full fund, and not as redeploy.
   Can I still redeploy it?

Comment: Can you be more clear on what changes you made in your program and the exact error message

Answer (score 1):

This might be an issue with the command you're using. To redeploy the program, you must run

```
solana program deploy ./target/deploy/*.so --program-id ABxhuh61R8QsvQFCmqy....
```

You can read more from the help for the command:

```
solana program deploy -h
```